# Show that $f(1)\ge 2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and that $f(x)\ge 2$ $\hspace{5pt}$  if $\hspace{5pt}$ $0\le x<1$.

Since $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, as $\{x_n\}\rightarrow 1$, $\{f(x_n)\}\rightarrow f(1)$.

Since $f(x)\ge 2, f(1)\ge 2$.

Is this enough, or did I oversimplify the proof?

Comment: Looks good! I suppose you could write $f(x_n)$ instead of $f(x)$ in line 3 and clarify that convergence preserves order, but your proof is fine.

Comment: Just making sure! My only concern was that 1 is not included when we say $f(x)\ge 2$, but my thought is that since it is continuous there, $f$ will still be greater than or equal to $2$ when $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Another proof:**

Suppose that $f(1)<2$. So there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(1)+\epsilon <2$. But $f$ is continuous at $1$ and then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$0<|x-1|<\delta \Rightarrow 0< |f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon.$$ But this contradicts the hypothesis that $f(x)\geq 2$ for every $x\in [0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would write that in any neighbourhood of 1, there exists a point where:
$$f(x) \geq 2.$$

So, I proceed by contradiction. Suppose f(1) < 2. Then simply pick:
$$\varepsilon = \frac{2-f(1)}{2} > 0 $$
and we have a contradiction.

This completes the proof.